# Using FOREACH statement in controller to get records to use for sitemap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using a tutorial that creates a sitemap XML. However i am changing things so it uses a database instead of current code. I have placed a Foreach statement in the controller to retrieve the information as a list and that code seems to be okay. The rest of the code in the action doesn't seem to like it. I am sure it is something that is looking me right in the face but i am not seeing it. Could someone direct me as to what might be the issue or if i am missing something in my code.

Here is the controller Action: (I have left the original code in it, but is commented out)

```
public ActionResult GenerateSiteMap()
    {

        var sitemapItems = new List<SitemapItem> {

        foreach (var items in db.Sitemaps)
        {
            new SitemapItem(Url.Action(items.Location), changeFrequency: SitemapChangeFrequency.Daily, priority: (items.Priority), lastModified: (items.LastModified));
        }
        //new SitemapItem(Url.Action("index", "home"), changeFrequency: SitemapChangeFrequency.Always, priority: 1.0),
        //new SitemapItem(Url.Action("about", "home"), lastModified: DateTime.Now),
        //new SitemapItem(PathUtils.CombinePaths(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority), "/home/list"))
        }

        SitemapGenerator sg = new SitemapGenerator();
        var doc = sg.GenerateSiteMap(sitemapItems);

        doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Sitemap.xml"));

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

I am getting a not all code paths return a value.

Thanks for your help!

Update:
Could this be it? It seemed to clear the error..

```
 public ActionResult GenerateSiteMap()
    {

        var sitemapItems = new List<SitemapItem>(); 

        foreach (var items in db.Sitemaps)
        {
            new SitemapItem(Url.Action(items.Location), changeFrequency: SitemapChangeFrequency.Daily, priority: (items.Priority), lastModified: (items.LastModified));
        }
        //new SitemapItem(Url.Action("index", "home"), changeFrequency: SitemapChangeFrequency.Always, priority: 1.0),
        //new SitemapItem(Url.Action("about", "home"), lastModified: DateTime.Now),
        //new SitemapItem(PathUtils.CombinePaths(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority), "/home/list"))


        SitemapGenerator sg = new SitemapGenerator();
        var doc = sg.GenerateSiteMap(sitemapItems);

        doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Sitemap.xml"));

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't place a `foreach` inside an object initializer like that, but you can use `Linq` to return an `IEnumerable` of sitemaps like:

```
// This assumes your code to initialize a sitemap is otherwise correct
var sitemapItems = db.Sitemaps
    .Select(sitemap => new SitemapItem(Url.Action(sitemap.Location),
        changeFrequency: SitemapChangeFrequency.Daily,
        priority: sitemap.Priority, lastModified: sitemap.LastModified))
    .ToList();
```

After your edit, you *almost* had it right. Inside your `foreach` loop, you need to `Add` the sitemap to your list, so this is another way to do it:

```
var sitemapItems = new List<SitemapItem>(); 

foreach (var items in db.Sitemaps)
{
    sitemapItems.Add(new SitemapItem(Url.Action(items.Location), 
        changeFrequency: SitemapChangeFrequency.Daily, priority: (items.Priority), 
        lastModified: (items.LastModified)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will try this in a bit and mark it as correct when it runs properly. If not ill add comment. You are missing a parentheses at the end. there should be 3.